# module _bsddb not found error when trying to install planet library on Mac OS X

Tags: python, mac

I'm trying to install [planet](http://www.planetplanet.org/), but I get an error:

```
/Users/john/Projects/planetprocessing/planet-2.0/planet/__init__.py:33: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from planet import __version__ as VERSION
  File "/Users/john/Projects/planetprocessing/planet-2.0/planet/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import dbhash
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/dbhash.py", line 8, in <module>
     import bsddb
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/bsddb/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
     import _bsddb
ImportError: No module named _bsddb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814041/how-to-fix-the-broken-bsddb-install-in-the-default-python-package-on-mac-os-x-10), it seems there are problems installing correctly bsddb module on Mac OS X.

If you follow the patch [described there](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/), you should be able to use bsddb module.